# Binary THEN Sequential Search if size of search list reduces to less then certain amount

Tags: c++, arrays, search, binary-search, sequential

Still new to C++ here. I am writing a program that compares two different search's comparison counts, a binary search alone and a binary search that switches to a sequential search once the search list size is lower than 18.

The array is of size 1000, randomly generated values (1-1000), and is sorted before searching.

The binary search works fine with a max comparison count of 10 I believe.

However, the combo search repeats forever if the sequential search loop starts.

Here is the combo search function:

```
template <class T>
void BinaryandSequentialSearch(const T arr[], int n, const T& search_key)
{
  int arrBegin = 0;
  int arrEnd = n - 1;
  int count = 0;
  int middle, i, newListSize;
  bool found = false;

  while (!found && arrBegin <= arrEnd)
  {
    count++;
    middle = (arrBegin + arrEnd) / 2;

    if (arr[middle] == search_key)
      found = true;
    else if (arr[middle] < search_key)
      arrBegin = middle + 1;
    else if (arrEnd - arrBegin < 18)
      {
        cout << "\nEntered sequenctial search.\n";
        newListSize = arrEnd - arrBegin;
        cout << newListSize << endl;

        for (i = 0; i < newListSize; i++)
        {
          count++;
          if (arr[middle] == search_key)
          {
            found = true;
            break;
          }
          middle++;
        }
      }
    else
      arrEnd = middle - 1;
  } 

  if (!found)
    cout << "\nThe value " << search_key << " is not in the array\n";
  else
  {
    cout << "\nThe value is located at index " << middle << " in the array"
         << endl << "Number of comparisons = " << count << endl;
  }
}
```

Even if newListSize = 6, the for loop seems to loop forever.

Here's my main function if any context is needed:

```
int main()
{
  const int size = 1000;
  int A[size];
  int search_key;
  srand (time(NULL));

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    A[i] = rand() % 1000 + 1;

  Print(A, size, "Random unsorted array:");
  BubbleSort<int>(A, size);
  Print(A, size, "Array Sorted:");

  cout << "Enter an integer you want to search from array: ";
  cin >> search_key;

  //BinarySearch(A, size, search_key);
  BinaryandSequentialSearch(A, size, search_key);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *The array is of size 1000* -- That's all?  That is hardly anything.  Try a million elements.  And of course `std::vector<int> A(size);` instead, so that the array elements are allocated from the heap, not the stack.

Answer (score 0):

After completing the sequential search, judging by the logic of your program, the loop should **break**. Or else, you will enter this line again:

```
while (!found && arrBegin <= arrEnd)
```

If `found` is false the first time through, since the sequential search did not change `arrBegin` and `arrEnd`, this loop will enter the sequential search again, and again, and again...

(So, it's not your `for` loop that's looping forever, it's your `while` loop that repeatedly executes the for loop).

It's an easy fix. See below.

```
else if (arrEnd - arrBegin < 18)
      {
        cout << "\nEntered sequenctial search.\n";
        newListSize = arrEnd - arrBegin;
        cout << newListSize << endl;

        for (i = 0; i < newListSize; i++)
        {
          count++;
          if (arr[middle] == search_key)
          {
            found = true;
            break;
          }
          middle++;
        }
        break; // <--- I did something!!
      }
```

Comment: This does fix the looping issue. However, "found" is never set to true if arr[middle] == search_key and it will always print that the value is not in the array if sequential search is entered.